# What language is Optimus Prime using to speak to this character?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

In *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, when

> Optimus Prime enters the ship, and uses the sword to free Grimlock,

he says something to him in another language.

I noticed that a similar language is used when

> Lockdown commands his wolf transformers to hunt down the ship's intruder.

Was this language previously used in the *Transformers* universe, apart from the Michael Bay films?

Comment: Probably Cybertronian. We hear the Decepticons speaking it briefly in the first movie.

Comment: You video link is dead. I'm removing it for now; please consider replacing it

Answer (score 3):

This could be Cybertronian language. [As TFWiki says](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Cybertronian_language), in Cybertron "conversations originally flowed in odd electronic syllables past strange metallic lips". This is the kind of sound we hear in the movie.

Comment: The problem with a wiki link is that literally anyone can write literally anything. There's no proof that this information is correct.